# Snapping raster grids in R

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial, raster

I am trying to align two raster grids in R. Once aligned I would like to be able to add them together.

I have tried to check whether making a stack would work:

```
grid_snap <- stack(GLC2000_sdw, afriPop_sdw)
```

And I get the following error:

> Error in compareRaster(x) : different extent

The raster grids have the following properties:

```
show(habi_sdw)
# class       : RasterLayer 
# dimensions  : 9187, 9717, 89270079  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution  : 0.00892857, 0.00892857  (x, y)
# extent      : -28.83706, 57.92186, -36.02464, 46.00214  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs 
# data source : C:\Users\di39\AppData\Local\Temp\R_raster_di39\raster_tmp_2015-08-12_172902_12860_17067.grd 
# names       : layer 
# values      : 0, 333707.6  (min, max)

show(Pop_sdw)
# class       : RasterLayer 
# dimensions  : 10143, 8858, 89846694  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
# extent      : -17.53524, 56.28143, -46.97893, 37.54607  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
# data source : C:\Users\di39\AppData\Local\Temp\R_raster_di39\raster_tmp_2015-08-12_170421_12860_12760.grd 
# names       : pop2010ppp 
# values      : 0, 128925.9  (min, max)
```

Using `alignExtent()` in the `raster` package seems not to be the correct approach.

Do I need to resample because the resolutions are slightly different?

(0.00892857 x 0.00892857) vs (0.008333333 vs 0.008333333)

Comment: The error message says that your objects have different extents. You cannot stack objects with different extents. You could have ask your question here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r

Answer (score 0):

First use `resample(GLC2000_sdw, afriPop_sdw, method="ngb")` and then `crop (GLC2000_sdw,  afriPop_sdw)` to make sure they have the same extent.